# Symfony 2 - Checkbox with default Value unless Data From Database

Tags: php, symfony, checkbox

I have a check box that Renders correctly . If there is no data from the database I want the check box to be checked by default.

If I set `"data" = True` it displays the checkbox checked. Now if I get the data from the database it won't override the checkbox to the boolean value of false. If I remove the data" => true then I am able to get the correct checkbox from the database but I am not able to set the default checkbox.

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('isFieldFirstname', 'checkbox', array(
        'label'    => 'Show First Name',
        'required' => false,
            "data" => true,
            )
                )
```

Just to recap

1. Database - No record found - show default checkbox as checked
2. If record found use value from database ex isFieldFirstname = false checkbox unchecked

Comment: Try to set the value as `true` in the entity `__construct()` function.

Comment: @A.L thanks for your response. I tried that but it seems that data option is called last.

Comment: If `__construct()` set the default value of `isFieldFirstname` as `true` and you pass it to the form, you shouldn't need to use the `data` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You implement a `buildForm` method to describe the structure of the form, not the values. The values are from a plain array or a data object. Symfony uses the DataAccess component to map them.

- drop "data" option in your checkbox
- call your checkbox "fieldFirstname" (no "is")

**// MyFormType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
  $builder
    ->add(
      'fieldFirstname',
      'checkbox',
      [
        'label'    => 'Show First Name',
        'required' => false
      ]
    );
}
```

- create a data class

**// MyFormData.php**

```
class MyFormData {
  private $fieldFirstname;

  public function isFieldFirstname() {
    return $this->fieldFirstname;
  }

  public function setFieldFirstname($fieldFirstname) {
    $this->fieldFirstname = $fieldFirstname;
  }
}
```

- create your action

**// MyController.php**

```
// ...
public function myAction() {
  $data = new MyFormData();
  $data->setFieldFirstname(
    ! $myService->isDataInDatabase()
  );

  $form = $this->createForm(
    new MyFormType(),
    $data
  );

  // ... 
}
```

Didn't test it right now, but should work.

Comment: Thank you i misunderstood the usage of "is" thanks for the detail clarification.

Comment: oh okay, if that was the problem, than have a look at the DataAccess component which is trying to access `public $x`, `isX()`, `getX()`, `hasX()` for reading `x` and `public $x`, `setX($x)` for writing `x` for objects. For arrays it's just the the key `$arr['x']` I think and also all methods of `ArrayAccess` (maybe I forgot some).